# Null Pointer Exception while selecting item of ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception

I am creating a list view and want to display the selected radio button's text as sub Item of it. Just testing it with Arraylist and not using simple adapter at the moment. That is not my concern right now but its the click event of ListView which shows NullPointerException. Refered few earlier posts too but wasn't helpful.

**WForecast.java**

```
public class WForecastHome extends Activity {

    ListView list;
    Button search;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.weatherforecast_home);

        search = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BTSearch);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        String[] s = new String[]{"Temparature format",
                "Update interval"};

        search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String> (WForecastHome.this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1 , s);
        list.setAdapter(aa);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Dialog dialog = new Dialog(WForecastHome.this);
                dialog.setTitle("Select temprature format");
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
                dialog.show();

                RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
                final RadioButton celcius = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.celcius);
                final RadioButton fahrenheit = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.fahrenheit);

                rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        switch(checkedId)
                        {
                        case R.id.celcius :
                            celcius.getText();
                            break;

                        case R.id.fahrenheit :
                            fahrenheit.getText();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }

}
```

**Logcat Error**

```
01-20 22:16:17.648: D/ddm-heap(333): Got feature list request
01-20 22:16:17.788: W/ResourceType(333): Skipping entry 0x7f020000 in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-20 22:16:21.528: W/ResourceType(333): Skipping entry 0x7f020000 in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-20 22:16:23.208: D/AndroidRuntime(333): Shutting down VM
01-20 22:16:23.208: W/dalvikvm(333): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001aa28)
01-20 22:16:23.208: E/AndroidRuntime(333): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
01-20 22:16:23.218: E/AndroidRuntime(333): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-20 22:16:23.218: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.nsa.WForecastHome$2.onItemClick(WForecastHome.java:61)
01-20 22:16:23.218: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
01-20 22:16:23.218: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3246)
01-20 22:16:23.218: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1635)
```

Requesting to help me identifying the error and what causing it.
Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to

```
 RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) dialog.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
 final RadioButton celcius = (RadioButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.celcius);
 final RadioButton fahrenheit = (RadioButton)dialog. findViewById(R.id.fahrenheit);
```

I guess you have the views in `dialog.xml`. So initialize your views as above.

`findViewById` looks for a view with the id in the current inflated layout. In your case you set the custom layout to dialog. So use the dialog object to initialize your views

Comment: is this causing error?? If yes, how? Sorry, did not get the logic.

Comment: @Saggy show your dialog.xml. if you have radiobutton in dialog.xml then you should initialize them as suggested in my post. What is the logic that you din't get?. its NUllPointerExcpetion indicating that something on line 61 is null. What is line 61 in your code

Comment: Yes I have all the views including radiobutton in dialog.xml only. The point I didn't get is why we need to add "dialog" in dialog.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1); and further. I haven't use this way earlier and all my program is working. Tough this solved my problem here.

Comment: Line 61 refers to rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()

Comment: @Saggy do check my edit, your comment only confirms what i suspected